# Adding Heavy UI in in each ListView Item

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-listview, out-of-memory

I am bit more concern of OOM on having a heavy UI on each item of a listview, example I have 100 items.
Below is the image that I wanted to practice and copy the UI layout. What would be the possible layout or how can I implement this type of UI. Each items are scrollable until the bottom, with separate contents but same layout. Please see my update below.

[image]

**Update:** I am planning to use **card ListVIew**, please guide me.

Comment: Please justify your down vote. I have experiences with OOM, your advises on how to do this layout is a great help.

Comment: I guess it's down vote is because this is an ordinal task to do in Android and it should not be asked here. You have to create your own layout for your list item row and provide it to adapter. If the problem is that you don't know how to create such a layout for your row,than you should learn how to create layouts :)

Comment: I have no problem with the layout creation, but bit more concern with OOM, let say I have created this type of scrollable UI, then I encountered OOM issues at the last part. I mean some layouts possible  prone to OOM.

Comment: if you get OOM,is because of your bitmaps, to solve this try to follow the steps from [HERE](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html)
also it will be better to use normal ListView instead of card ListVIew (as the creator of the card ListView wrote it can give you OOM bevause it doesn't have recylce mechanism like ListView)

Comment: I've been optimizing my codes with soft and weak references, and display and resize my images according to what is needed.

Comment: Anyway because the "card ListView" implementation does not recycle views you will get OOM. That's way you should use normal ListView mechanism instead of "card ListView" implementation.If you will change your code to use ListView you will be free of OOM :).
P.S: i have a gridView in my app that has it's elements consists of ImageVies and textViews and i don't get any OOM event i have an arraylist of size >5000.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis @Eddy and the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple listView or card ListView but make sure listView raw does not have many nested layout for avoiding nested hierarchy **you should use Relative Layout in list raw**

Comment: `Nested weights are bad for performance` I just knew that, thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

I think using a listview with custom row layout will be better for your app.This will help you to reuse the same layouts which are inflated when loading listview.Also please check the size of images you used in the rows.